# Typescript: Any way to define object shape within a class?

Tags: typescript

I would like to specify an object shape. I think this is normally done with an Interface:

```
interface DesiredResponseShape {
  status: string
  , optionalMessage: string|null 
}

class Example {
  callApi() : Promise<object> {
    const response = fetch(...)
    const json: DesiredResponseShape = response.json();
  }
}
```

This example is small enough that clarity isn't hurt by the interface definition being outside the class. From my reading, interfaces can not be defined inside classes without resorting to undesirable patterns. Is there any other way to define the desired shape of a variable inside the class close to its point of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline your interface:

```
const json: {
  status: string
  , optionalMessage: string|null 
}
= response.json();
```